# Regex multisubstrings from string

Tags: python, regex

I should be able to work this out, but I'm obviously missing something.

Given this line:

```
<190>1 2020-12-22T15:23:46+00:00 192.168.2.1 dhcpd - - - dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.2.11 from c0:ee:fb:f5:d8:da (OnePlus3) via igb2
```

How can i extract the date/time AND everything after dhcpd: please?

I've tried

```
import re
string = '<190>1 2020-12-22T15:23:46+00:00 192.168.2.1 dhcpd - - - dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.2.11 from c0:ee:fb:f5:d8:da (OnePlus3) via igb2'
r = re.compile ("\d{4}-\d{2}-\S{17}")
r.findall(string)
```

This works fine - if i try to add `dhcpd:.+` though, it stops working.

What am i doing wrong please?  This will go in a script to pull lines out of my dhcp logs.  The rest i can handle.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try `"\d{4}-\d{2}-\S{17}.*(dhcpd: .*)"`? This saves everything starting from `dhcpd:` onwards

Comment: I lose the date if i use that pattern I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r = re.compile (r"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\S{17}).*dhcpd(.+)$")
print( r.findall(string) )
```